# Implementing stack with python to validate braces

Tags: python, list, stack

I have written a python script to check validity of braces. I implemented stack, for every '{' I I do stack push operation and for every '}' I do stack pop and see if it's empty. But I am not able to figure put what's wrong with my code.

```
class Stack(object) : 
  def __init__(self) : 
    self.items = [] 

  def push(self, item) : 
    self.items.append(item) 

  def pop(self) : 
    return self.items.pop() 

  def isEmpty(self) : 
    return (self.items == [])

  def getStack(self) :
    return self.items

def check_braces(file_data):
    stack = Stack()
    for char in file_data:
        if char == '{':
            stack.push('{')
            #print stack.getStack()
        if char == '}':
            stack.pop()
            #print stack.getStack()
            if stack.isEmpty():
                #print stack.isEmpty()
                return 'braces are valid'
    return 'braces are invalid'

myData = ['{', 'a:', '"1",', 'b:', '{', 'a:', '"2",', 'b:', '{', 'a:', '"7",', 'b:', '{', 'a:', '"14"', '}', '}', '},', 'b:', '{', 'a:', '"3",', 'b:', '{', 'a:', '"8"', '},', 'b:', '{', 'a:', '"9"', '}', '},', 'b:', '{', 'a:', '"4",', 'b:', '{', 'a:', '"10"', '},', 'b:', '{', 'a:', '"11",', 'b:', '{', 'a:', '"15"', '}', '}', '},', 'b:', '{', 'a:', '"5"', '},', 'b:', '{', 'a:', '"6",', 'b:', '{', 'a:', '"12"', '},', 'b:', '{', 'a:', '"13",', 'b:', '{', 'a:', '16', '},', 'b:', '{', 'a:', '17', '},', 'b:', '{', 'a:', '18', '}', '}', '}', '}']

print check_braces(myData)
```

Comment: Well, what *is* wrong with it? (I downvoted because this doesn't provide sample input and expected/actual results.) At least one error is that `stack.pop()` might be called on an empty stack.

Comment: According to your code `{}{{{{` would be valid, because after the first (and only) `}` the stack is empty. You have to check two cases: You try to pop from an empty stack -> invalid. After the last input item, the stack is not empty -> invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is perfectly fine, but your input(`myData`) is faulty.

Use the following instead -

`myData = ['{', 'a:', '"1",', 'b:', '{', 'a:', '"2",', 'b:', '{', 'a:', '"7",', 'b:', '{', 'a:', '"14"', '}', '}', '}', 'b:', '{', 'a:', '"3",', 'b:', '{', 'a:', '"8"', '}', 'b:', '{', 'a:', '"9"', '}', '}', 'b:', '{', 'a:', '"4",', 'b:', '{', 'a:', '"10"', '}', 'b:', '{', 'a:', '"11",', 'b:', '{', 'a:', '"15"', '}', '}', '}', 'b:', '{', 'a:', '"5"', '}', 'b:', '{', 'a:', '"6",', 'b:', '{', 'a:', '"12"', '}', 'b:', '{', 'a:', '"13",', 'b:', '{', 'a:', '16', '}', 'b:', '{', 'a:', '17', '}', 'b:', '{', 'a:', '18', '}', '}', '}', '}']`

There are few `'},'` entries in your input which should be `'}'`

Answer (score 1):

As said in my comment you have to check for two cases:

```
class Stack (list):
        def push (self, x):
                return self.append (x)

def check_braces (data):
        stack = Stack ()
        for c in data:
                if c == '{':
                        stack.push (c)
                if c == '}':
                        if not stack: return False #First case: too many closing
                        stack.pop ()
        return not stack #Second case too many opening

print (check_braces ('{}}') )
print (check_braces ('{{}') )
print (check_braces ('{}{') )
print (check_braces ('}{}') )
print (check_braces ('{}{}{{}}') )
```

But as the only important thing about the stack is its depth, you can simply use:

```
def check_braces (data):
        depth = 0
        for c in data:
                if c == '{':
                        depth += 1
                if c == '}':
                        if not depth: return False
                        depth -= 1
        return depth == 0
```

Comment: Thank you for replying! Though your answer is helpful to me, but it wasn't exactly answering what's wrong with my code with the given input data. Thats why I had to accept other answer (and upvote yours). However I will be using this logic in my code =)

Comment: Just bear in mind that what theharshest said is not true: "Your code is perfectly fine". If you use `myData = ['{', '}', '}']`, your code will say "braces are valid", although they obviously are not.

Comment: yup! I know ;-) I saw your example in the comments and I realized the mistake in my code. Now I am modifying it